# How to connect the private blockchain bootnode and node on elastic ip of aws

Tags: bootnodes

When we are connecting the bootnode with this 0.0.0.0:30301

'''./bootnode -nodekey "./boot.key" -verbosity 7 -addr "0.0.0.0:30310"'''
it show multiple peer from different ips I connection with my elastic ip
how to connection with elastic ip